# Discord py, How to remove permissions using role metnion

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to remove the the role from the users in the server who have the corresponding role by using the role mention.
For example, '%remove_role@TEAM_A' removes 'TEAM_A' from the roles of people who have the role 'TEAM_A'.
I searched hard on Google, but I couldn't find an answer or a way to do it, so I made it myself, but I failed to complete it, so I wrote a question here.

- 1st. %rmrole team name
- 2nd. Check if the team name you entered is in 'role_list'.
- 3rd. Remove the role of the team name entered from users on the server.

this is my code.

```
@bot.command()
async def rmrole(ctx, team_name):
    key = 0
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name=team_name)
    team_list = []
    print(role)
    # typo check
    role_list = ["TEAM_A", "TEAM_B", "TEAM_C", "TEAM_D"]
    if role in role_list:
        type_error = 1
    else:
        type_error = 0

    # remove_role
    empty = True
    if type_error == 1:
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            if role in member.roles:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                empty = False
        if empty:
            await ctx.send("anyone has this role.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("check the typos."
```

```
async def remove_role(ctx, role: discord.Role)
```

I was worried that if I write like this, users would get a lot of alarms.
Thus, in the body, I enter the name of the role in text, and I write  it in a way that scans the role in the code.

The '#remove_role' part was searched and found.
The code was executed, but the role was not removed.

I wonder where the wrong part is, and I need help to make what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is simple:

```
role_list = ["TEAM_A", "TEAM_B", "TEAM_C", "TEAM_D"]
if role in role_list:
    type_error = 1
else:
    type_error = 0
```

This code will always fail and lead to `type_error = 0`, as `role` is a `discord.role.Role` class and not a string. This means comparing the role you got via `get` and a string representing its name will always fail : and so, that the second part of your code that removes the role is never accessed. It works otherwise.

Instead, you want:

```
if role.name in role_list:
    type_error = 1
else:
    type_error = 0
```

Or better yet, this instead:

```
if role is None:
    return await ctx.send("Role doesn't exist")
```

...since I don't quite see the point of your code personally: if `role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name=team_name)` fails (i.e the role doesn't exist), `role` will be `None`, and you can easily check for it instead of comparing it against a hardcoded list.